# Batch copy a specific file to all directories and subdirectories

Tags: batch-file

i have a folder in c:\folders directory with around 6000 subfolders named with different numbers and each subfolder has 2 more subfolders called "medium" and "thumbs".

I need to copy a file called index.html which is located in c:\folders into ALL 6000 folders and into all medium and thumbs subfolders of each one of the 6000 folders.

I am trying to build some batch code like this

```
for /D %%D in ("C:\folders\*.*") do (
pushd "%%~D"
copy "index.html"
copy "index.html" "medium\"
copy "index.html" "thumbs\"
popd
)
```

but this is not working. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The problem is that you did not specify the full path of the source file `C:\folders\index.html`, which is mandatory as you change the working directory within each `for` loop iteration; the rest of your code should be fine...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the job if it's for every subfolder

```
set "source=full path of index.html"
for /f "delims=" %%D in ('dir /b /s /ad "C:\folders\*") do (
  copy "%source%" "%%~D"
)
```

edit:
to suppress output in console add `>nul` in `copy` command line
to not overwrite index.html files, replace `copy` by `echo n|copy /-y`

```
set "source=full path of index.html"
for /f "delims=" %%D in ('dir /b /s /ad "C:\folders\*") do (
  echo n|copy /-y "%source%" "%%~D">nul
)
```

http://ss64.com/nt/copy.html